# Как добавить заголовок для XtraGrid?

Tags: c#, devexpress, winforms, gridview

Делаю экспорт XtraChart и XtraGrid в один файл excel:

```
CompositeLink compositeLink = new CompositeLink();
compositeLink.PrintingSystem = new PrintingSystem();
PrintableComponentLink link = new PrintableComponentLink(new PrintingSystem());
link.Component = controlChart1;                 
compositeLink.Links.Add(link);
link = new PrintableComponentLink();
link.Component = gridControl1;
compositeLink.Links.Add(link);
compositeLink.ExportToXls("file.xls");
```

Мне необходимо добавить заголовок для моей таблицы (XtraGrid). Как это сделать? Мне пойдет, даже если как-то вставить Label. Я так сделал для Winforms Chart`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Тут есть несколько вариантов:

**0. Заголовок в самом `GridView`**

С помощью свойства [`GridView.ViewCaption`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseBaseView_ViewCaptiontopic) можно задать заголовок для Вашего `GridView` и отобразить его при помощи свойства [`GridView.OptionsView.ShowViewCaption`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnViewOptionsView_ShowViewCaptiontopic).
Пример:

```
//Где-то в коде.

gridView1.ViewCaption = "Заголовок";
gridView1.OptionsView.ShowViewCaption = true;

//Ваш код без изменений.

CompositeLink compositeLink = new CompositeLink();
compositeLink.PrintingSystem = new PrintingSystem();
PrintableComponentLink link = new PrintableComponentLink(new PrintingSystem());
link.Component = controlChart1;                 
compositeLink.Links.Add(link);
link = new PrintableComponentLink();
link.Component = gridControl1;
compositeLink.Links.Add(link);
compositeLink.ExportToXls("file.xls");
```

**1. Объекты классов `TextBrick` и `Link`**

С помощью класса [`Link`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraPrintingLinktopic) можно подготовить собственный вывод на печать путём использования объектов классов, производных от класса [`Brick`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument88). В данном конкретном случае это будет объект класса [`TextBrick`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressXtraPrintingTextBricktopic.aspx). Для этого достаточно будет подписаться на событие [`LinkBase.CreateDetailArea`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingLinkBase_CreateDetailAreatopic) и воспользоваться методом [`e.Graph.DrawBrick`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraPrintingBrickGraphics_DrawBricktopic(ZhJzCQ)) для прорисовки заголовка.
Пример:

```
var compositeLink = new CompositeLink();
compositeLink.PrintingSystem = new PrintingSystem();

var link = new PrintableComponentLink(new PrintingSystem());
link.Component = controlChart1;               
compositeLink.Links.Add(link);

var gridTitleLink = new Link();
gridTitleLink.CreateDetailArea += (s, e) =>
{
    var textBrick = new TextBrick();
    textBrick.Text = "Заголовок";
    textBrick.Font = new Font("Arial", 15);
    textBrick.Rect = new RectangleF(0, 0, 300, 25);
    textBrick.BorderWidth = 0;
    textBrick.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    textBrick.HorzAlignment = HorzAlignment.Near;

    e.Graph.DrawBrick(textBrick);
};

compositeLink.Links.Add(gridTitleLink);

link = new PrintableComponentLink();
link.Component = gridControl1;
compositeLink.Links.Add(link);

compositeLink.ExportToXls("file.xls");
```